# WMI: Change IP address by fetching ip column in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

**First Process:**

1. Get the column ip_address,subnet from database
2. I will set the column ip address to **label1.text** and subnet to **label2.text**

**string connection = "Server=192.168.1.10;Database=xxxxx;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;";**

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();

    var query = "SELECT TOP 1 ip_address,subnet,gateway FROM computer_info WHERE pc_name = HOST_NAME() ORDER BY id DESC";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        // column ip
        string ip_address = dr["ip_address"].ToString();
        string sub_net = dr["subnet"].ToString();
        string gateway = dr["gateway"].ToString();

        label1.Text = ip_address;
        label2.Text = sub_net;
    }

    conn.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

**Second Process:**

1. I want to change my ip address and my subnet

   Note: the value of ip address and subnet is from database

   ```
   public void setIP(string ip_address, string subnet_mask)
   {
       ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
       ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

       foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
       {
           if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
           {
               try
               {
                   ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                   ManagementBaseObject newIP =
                       objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

                   newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_address };
                   newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet_mask };

                   setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   throw;
               }


           }
       }
   }
   ```

Third process execute

Note: I have 2 example code here **1** is working and **2** not working

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setIP(
            // if i use this static string value my address is changing.
            "192.168.1.5",
            "255.255.255.0"
          );

        ///---------------------------------------///////////////////////////////////////

        setIP(
            //the value inside of label1 , label2 is from database. ??? the question is why there is no result if the value came from the database.
            label1.Text,
            label2.Text

            );
    }
```

I hope you will help me guys.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure my connection string is working. This the only thing I can see. Check while stepping through your code to see if you get a value back. Also make sure your router and modem have port forwarding on if you are trying to reach a database on your domain. However, if your trying to reach a server outside the network then I would definitely make sure you can reach the server by ping the server.

Comment: what do you mean. the value from the database is not working? or set to the labels?

Comment: when you step through your code on the line where it say:

Comment: string ip_address = dr["ip_address"].ToString();

Comment: when i try to messagebox.show that string the value in the database is showing.

Comment: the value of that is 192.168.1.5

Comment: You should be able to hover over this line when stepping through it and see something in the string ip_address to tell you are getting back something from the server if you don't see anything then.  Check your connection string  or see if you can ping the server through the command prompt

Comment: sorry I said server I meant database.

Comment: Ok so you are getting the IP address back from the database but that IP address is not showing up in label1.Text,
            label2.Text

Comment: So, your connecting to a local host. Which tells me that the database is on your computer. So if that is the case all you need is the database name not the IP address in your connection string.

Comment: setIP(
            // if i use this static string value my address is changing.
            "192.168.1.5",
            "255.255.255.0"
          );

I see you calling the method from an event which is fine but I noticed your hardcoding the IP address instead of passing what your given from the database assuming you are getting something back from the database. When you should be passing what ever you get from the data reader string ip_address = dr["ip_address"].ToString(); to the Method setIP

Comment: you can do this using an accessor and passing to this accessor what the data reader give you then use the button1_Click_1 to call the accessor. Another approach also is to have a global variable that can be reached outside of your class but  this posses a security risk. Accessor is  a safe way to go. Because as it stands label1.Text and   label2.Text are out of scope in the first process from your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to debug is to set BreakPoint at setIP function and view the value of label2.Text in "Immediate Window" [To open Immediate Window in VS menu : Debug -> Window -> Immediate Window]. Please confirm whether you are getting value here. If you are not getting value here, share your front-end label tag you have used.